# How to add inheritance structure to a class, referring to "enable_share_on_this"

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm working on a C++ class, to which I'd like to add an inheritance structure, but recently my colleagues have added a `enable_shared_from_this`, blocking the possibility to add an inheritance structure. Does anybody know the correct syntax?

Thanks in advance

Current implementation:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE Own_Class
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<Own_Class>
{
public:
    Own_Class();
```

First try:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE Own_Class : public NONSENSE
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<Own_Class>
{
public:
    Own_Class();

=>C2143 : syntax error : missing ',' before 'public'
```

Second try:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE Own_Class :
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<Own_Class> : : public NONSENSE
{
public:
    Own_Class();
=>C2143 : syntax error : missing ',' before 'public'
```

Third try (quite desperate):

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE Own_Class :
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<Own_Class : public NONSENSE>
{
public:
    Own_Class();
=>C2059 : syntax error ':'
```

(Sorry for the sarcastic tone, but it's really frustrating)

Comment: Have you tried : `public NONSENSE,
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<Own_Class>` just like your first try but with a comma ?

Comment: You might want to go back to your books, tutorials or class-notes and check out how multiple inheritance is done. The first error message you show is *very* clear about the issue and also should give you a clue about how to solve it.

Comment: You should take a close look at what the compiler told you: `syntax error : missing ',' before 'public'`. So it should be `public NONSENSE,  public std::enable_shared_from_this<Own_Class>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax to use multiple inheritance in C++ is the following :

```
class SomeClass : public InheritA, public InheritB
{
  // [...]
}
```

So in your case the following should work :

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE Own_Class : public NONSENSE, public std::enable_shared_from_this<Own_Class>
{
  // [...]
}
```